# Solving $x^n \equiv a \text{ (mod } p)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, congruences

I want to show that for any integers $a$ and $n,$ ($n > 1$) there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $$x^n \equiv a \text{ (mod } p).$$

When $n$ is odd, I used the fact that  if $(a,p)=1$ and if $a^{\frac{p-1}{(n,p-1)}} \equiv 1 \text{ (mod } p), $ then $x^n \equiv a \text{ (mod } p)$ has $(n,p-1)$ solutions. Then [Dirichlet's theorem on Arithmetic Progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) , there are infinitely many primes $p \equiv 2 \text{ (mod } n)$ and hence $(n,p-1) = 1.$

How do I complete the case when $n$ is odd?

P.S.: This problems also appears as [problem #3 on Chapter 5, page 342](http://books.google.com/books?id=njgVUjjO-EAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=power%20residue%20modulo&f=false) of Borevich-Shafarevich's Number Theory book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is analogous to Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes. We do not need Dirichlet's theorem. 
Let $M$ be the set of primes $p$ such that there exists an integer $x$ with $x^n\equiv a \bmod p$. Let $P(x)=x^n-a$. Then we can write the congruence as $P(x)\equiv 0 \bmod p$.
Suppose that $M$ is *finite*, i.e., $M=\{ p_1,\ldots ,p_k\}$. For each integer $m$, $P(mp_1p_2\cdots p_k)$ is an integer with no prime factors, which must equal then $1$ or $-1$. However, since $P$ has degree $n\geq 2$, it takes each of the values 1 and -1 at most $n$ times, a contradiction.

Comment: In your proof, it's assumed that (a,p)=1, which is fine. Thank you!